# Communicate between web server and raspberry pi

Tags: java, php, web

Assume that I have web server (ad-box.deslab.vn) and raspberry pi is a client connected to my web server. (Server and Client is not in local network)
Beside using socket, How can I send a string from web server to raspberry pi? 
What languages can I use to code for web server and client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQTT (MQ Telemetry Transport or Message Queue Telemetry Transport) which is an ISO standard publish-subscribe-based lightweight messaging protocol for use on top of the TCP/IP protocol. It is designed for connections with remote locations where a "small code footprint" is required or the network bandwidth is limited.

Below you can find the list of some MQTT clients in various languages.

http://www.hivemq.com/blog/seven-best-mqtt-client-tools

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9D84_1.0.0/com.ibm.mm.tc.doc/tc10100_.htm